# Displaying a Toolbar with React Portal, only when there are children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-portal

**GOAL:** Display the ToolkitArea only when the "#toolkitArea" has children

**PROBLEM:** I can't count the current amount of children inside the ToolkitArea for some reason

**WHAT I DID SO FAR:**

I have a component "Toolbar" and i want it to be displayed when Buttons are added via ReactPortal.

My current approach is having a UseEffect triggered inside the toolkitArea, checking for the amount of childrens inside the area.

```
import {  faEyeSlash, faEye } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import ToolkitButton from './ToolkitButton'
import { useState } from 'react'
export interface ToolkitAreaProps {
  children?: React.ReactNode

}
const ToolkitArea = ({ children }:ToolkitAreaProps) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState<boolean>(true)
  const [isEmpty, setEmpty] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const toolkit = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    const toolkitArea = (document.getElementById('toolkitArea') as HTMLDivElement)
    console.log(toolkitArea.children, '', toolkit.current?.children, toolkit.current?.children.length)
    if(toolkitArea.children.length > 0)
      setEmpty(false)
    else setEmpty(true)
  }, [toolkit])

  return <div className="fixed bottom-6 w-full h-16 z-40 px-8 md:pl-32 md:pr-16 flex">
    <div className={`-ml-4 md:-ml-12 rounded-md w-16 h-16 bg-indigo-700 flex items-center justify-center shadow shadow-black shadow-md ${(visible || isEmpty) ? 'invisible' : 'visible'}`}>
      <ToolkitButton icon={faEye} onClick={() => setVisible(true)} tooltip={'Show Toolbar'}/>
    </div>
    <div className={`h-full mx-auto bg-indigo-700 w-fit max-w-full rounded-md shadow shadow-black shadow-md py-2 flex px-4 overflow-x-auto md:overflow-x-visible ${(visible || isEmpty) ? 'invisible' : 'visible'}`}>
      <ToolkitButton icon={faEyeSlash} onClick={() => setVisible(false)} className="-order-1" tooltip={'Toggle Toolbar'}/>
      <div ref={toolkit} className={'w-fit flex gap-4 h-full pl-4'} id={'toolkitArea'}>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
} 

export default ToolkitArea
```

The output in the browser looks like this:
[image: Console.log collapsed]
[image: Console.log expanded]

It says the children.length is 0, even when there are 5 elements displayed.

I have no clue what is responsible for this behavior. I can only imagine, the Buttons are added after the useEffect triggers, and the console.log inside the browser is adapted.

How can I achieve my goal, to only display the whole toolkitArea, when there are children inside the toolkitArea?

Answer (score 0):

In general, React is not going to re-render your `ToolkitArea` component when the portal contents change, so the `useEffect` hook won't be triggered. Even if it did, you may not be able to depend on the rendering order to have an accurate view of how many children the `#toolkitArea` portal contains.

I would suggest using some slightly heavy machinery in the form of the [HTML5 `MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), and run a callback in your `ToolkitArea` whenever there's a change to the contents of the `#toolkitArea` div.

You can wrap the necessary logic in a hook:

```js
function useEmptyDetector(element: HTMLDivElement | null): boolean
{
  // Watch the given element and return true when it has no children

  const [isEmpty, setIsEmpty] = useState(!element || element.childElementCount === 0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (element) {
      // Watch for changes to the child list, and update isEmpty accordingly
      const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
        setIsEmpty(element.childElementCount === 0)
      });
      observer.observe(element, { childList: true });

      return () => observer.disconnect();  // cleanup when unmounted
    }
    else setIsEmpty(true);
  }, [element, setIsEmpty]);

  return isEmpty;
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-sutherland-biql4f?file=/src/App.tsx)

The hook returns a value `isEmpty` which you can then use in your component (note the use of a callback ref for `#toolkitArea` instead of the ref object):

```js
const ToolkitArea = ({ children }:ToolkitAreaProps) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState<boolean>(true)
  const [toolkit, setToolkit] = useState<HTMLDivElement>();
  const isEmpty = useEmptyDetector(toolkit);

  return <div className="fixed bottom-6 w-full h-16 z-40 px-8 md:pl-32 md:pr-16 flex">
    <div className={`-ml-4 md:-ml-12 rounded-md w-16 h-16 bg-indigo-700 flex items-center justify-center shadow shadow-black shadow-md ${(visible || isEmpty) ? 'invisible' : 'visible'}`}>
      <ToolkitButton icon={faEye} onClick={() => setVisible(true)} tooltip={'Show Toolbar'}/>
    </div>
    <div className={`h-full mx-auto bg-indigo-700 w-fit max-w-full rounded-md shadow shadow-black shadow-md py-2 flex px-4 overflow-x-auto md:overflow-x-visible ${(visible || isEmpty) ? 'invisible' : 'visible'}`}>
      <ToolkitButton icon={faEyeSlash} onClick={() => setVisible(false)} className="-order-1" tooltip={'Toggle Toolbar'}/>
      <div ref={setToolkit} className={'w-fit flex gap-4 h-full pl-4'} id={'toolkitArea'}>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```